# Try to get value from dll

Tags: c++, dll

I'm trying to take a value, the value change every sec .. and send it to the application every time .. I made a function and returned with him the number 60. when I call the function with the application, i saw the value that i returned. but what if I want take value from the dll, thats all the time change. and show it in the application ? for example, i have source of codecave in the Pinball game, that sohw me the score in console. the console it from the dll and I want take the score value and show it in my own application. how I can get the score from the dll to the application ? and get it in the real time ? Just to see the score in the dll's console and my own application ..

Comment: You've stated what you want. Now what have you tried to achieve that? What have you written already? Where are you stuck in the process?

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a library and want some symbols to be exported from here to another piece of code outside this library, the best approach is always to use a namespace.

MyExportedHeader.h and SomeCode.cpp should be compiled part of your library.

**MyExportedHeader.h**

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    extern int foo;
    extern float bar;
    extern int get_num();
};
```

**SomeCode.cpp**

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    int foo = 15;
    floar bar = 25;
    int get_num()
    {
        /* CALCULATE and return the current num */
    }
};
```

You can use the exported symbols in a piece of code outside the library in say MyApplication.cpp

**MyApplication.cpp**

```
#include <MyExportedHeader.h>
void somefn()
{
    int current_num = MyNamespace::get_num();
}
```

The only difference between this and directly declaring these variables/functions as globals is IF two libraries export the same set of symbols - there would be conflicts.

PS: If you're using constants, better to use Enums instead.

EDIT: Added a more simple and detailed example as per Idohadar's request.

Comment: Can you show me how i can use it with dll varible ? Just try to make a 'int' varible with value 15, and send it to the application ..

Comment: @Idohadar Updated the example to be much more clear and have shown how to access the varibale foo (with a value of 15 located in the library), outside the library.

Comment: I'm trying to take a value, the value change every sec ..
and send it to the application every time .. I made a function and returned with him the number 60. when I call the function with the application, i saw the value that i returned. but what if I want take value from the dll,

Comment: thats all the time change. and show it in the application ? for example, i have source of codecave in the Pinball game, that sohw me the score in console. the console it from the dll and I want take the score value and show it in my own application. how I can get the score from the dll to the application ? and get it in the real time ? Just to see the score in the dll's console and my own application ..

Comment: You need a function in your library which returns this value back to the caller i.e. the application. ;)

Comment: Check out the get_num() function in the example.

Answer (score 0):

If the symbol is exported, and you know its name, you can either include the header where it's declared and link against the library, or declare it yourself:

```
extern int whatever;
```

That's one option. The second one would be to have a getter function for it, export the getter and then dynamically call it to return your value - research `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: Tried, In the App:  

    typedef int(*FuncScore); FuncScore MyScore;
    
    MyScore = (FuncScore)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "MyScore");
    
    sprintf(Get, "Score: %d", MyScore);
    MsgInfo(Get);

In the DLL:

    extern int MyScore = 15;

Also tried:

    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int MyScore = 15;

And I'm loading the dll with the Loadlibrary,
With the function all go fine ..



And Ash ? Can u explane more of this .. ?

Comment: If you tried something, why don't you put it in your original question and maybe you'd stop getting downvotes.